# Blue/Green Deployment to IIS via TeamCity (On remote server)

Tags: iis, powershell, deployment, teamcity

We have a TeamCity instance that sits on an AWS server and then our production machines are on Bare Metal in a data center.

If we wanted to get Blue/Green deployment working and needed to run some Powershell on the live machine from the TeamCity instance, what steps do we need to take and I assume we can keep all this locked down via the firewall?